# Java Help Wanted with Scanner

Tags: java

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");
    int x = in.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println((x%2==0) ?  "Even" : "Odd");
```

How do i make this program into three lines including the Scanner? Meaning there are only three semicolons instead of four.

Comment: Please edit your title to summarize your specific issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2:

```
System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");
System.out.println((new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()%2==0) ?  "Even" : "Odd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `System.out.println(in.nextInt() % 2 == 0 ?  "Even" : "Odd");` and remove the line before.